# How to fix this service account creation error?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam

I am creating service account programmatically for project using java sbt play framework using google java sdk

[code sample](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/create)

but I'm getting this error response

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Permission iam.serviceAccountKeys.create is required to perform this operation on service account projects/from-gcloud-249112/serviceAccounts/bhavaay-anand-095@from-gcloud-249112.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Permission iam.serviceAccountKeys.create is required to perform this operation on service account projects/from-gcloud-249112/serviceAccounts/bhavaay-anand-095@from-gcloud-249112.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm using exact code from google code sample.

```
public ServiceAccount createServiceAccount(String projectId, String name, String displayName) throws IOException {
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
        credential =
                credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    }
    try {
         final Iam service = new Iam.Builder(
                GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                credential)
                .setApplicationName("service-accounts")
                .build();

        ServiceAccount serviceAccount = new ServiceAccount();
        serviceAccount.setDisplayName(displayName);
        CreateServiceAccountRequest request = new CreateServiceAccountRequest();
        request.setAccountId(name);
        request.setServiceAccount(serviceAccount);

        String serviceAccountEmail = "xxx";

        ServiceAccountKey key =
                service
                        .projects()
                        .serviceAccounts()
                        .keys()
                        .create(
                                "projects/" + projectId +"/serviceAccounts/" + serviceAccountEmail,
                                new CreateServiceAccountKeyRequest())
                        .execute();

        System.out.println("Created service account: " + serviceAccount);
        return serviceAccount;
    } catch(GeneralSecurityException e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you running your code? On your computer? On cloud shell?

Comment: on my computer, but why?

Comment: See the answer. It's for that, for diagnosing what is the default service account.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are missing the permission "iam.serviceAccountKeys.create" to perform that command.

i see that you are loading the default credentials:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
```

But did you set the proper credentials before?

Try doing

```
gcloud auth login
```

or

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

See more information about it [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable).